# Make child div fit inside parent without shifting to the left

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, width

I have a child div that is slightly larger than the parent:
[image]

When I change the width of the child to 100% it doesn't centre:
[image]

what I want is that it will be the same size as parent, and centred and have the side borders of the Tax column still aligned with the table borders:

css for the parent:

```
const HeaderRowContainer = styled.div(({ theme }) => ({
  height: '32px',
  backgroundColor: theme.alabaster,
  padding: '0',
  lineHeight: 1.2
}))
```

child:

```
const Container = styled.div(({ gutterSpacing, justifyContentEnd, alignItems, flexWrap }) => ({
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: alignItems || 'flex-start',
  boxSizing: 'border-box',
  flexDirection: 'row',
  flexWrap: flexWrap || 'wrap',
  flex: '0 1 auto',
  justifyContent: justifyContentEnd ? 'flex-end' : 'flex-start',
  marginLeft: `-${gutterSpacing}px`,
  marginRight: `-${gutterSpacing}px`
}))
```

Comment: Could you provide a complete example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: By the way, this can happen when child elements have fixed width so the total width can exceed its parent element